# Exchange 2010 security audit

Tags: exchange-2010, security

Our IT department has received reports from HR that managers are reading their subordinates email, and we've been tasked with identifying if there is a technical way to achieve this.  I'm looking for help identifying if this is possible or not.

We have confirmed that the Full Access Permission and delegated control is not enabled, but we do see that the Exchange Control Panel is accessible to all users.  I'm wondering if there is a way to look at actual emails in here (I have not found a way yet).

Can anyone think of a way to look at other users email without knowing the credentials?  Perhaps they're copying PST's from the local workstation if they know the local admin passwords of the users workstation?  Else, is there some auditing tools we can use to track any suspicious behavior down?  I've started reading about Administrator Audit Logging in 2010.

Any thoughts are appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

> identifying if there is a technical way to achieve this.

2:

1 - they get the subordinates password
2 - they get the suboridinate or someone with technical authority giving them read rights on the mailbox

> Perhaps they're copying PST's from the local workstation i

Assuming there is one - it should be an OST file.... it would mean cooperation of the user (or an utterly stupid user) as per standard those are in the user's private folders.

Occams razor points into managers having the passwords (simplest solution).